# Oracle like and between used together

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I thought this would have been an easy google search but couldn't find any solutions. Is there a way to use the like and between together in a query?

Example

```
REASON_CODES

A00 VMC B10
A00 RTD B19
.
.
.
A99 RNT B40
```

I am trying to write a query like:

```
Select count(*) from table_1 where REASON_CODES like between '%A10%' and '%A25%'
```

Is there a solution to do this? I was reading "convert" may do the trick but I had no luck.

Thanks

Comment: SQL Plus is used with Oracle, not MySQL.

Comment: Are you only looking for values starting with A10 to A25, or with those anywhere in the values? Your data suggests starting-with, but you used a leading % in your query?

Comment: Thanks Barmar for your input, The solution scaisEdge gave actually works for both MySQL and SQLPlus for anyone else with the same question. Google is usually not bias between the two since a lot of the queries are the same or have the same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use substring

```
  Select count(*) from table_1 
  where   substr(reason_codes, 1,3) between 'A10' and 'A25';
```

Comment: The OP's suggested pattern starts with % too, so `substr(..., 1, 3)`  won't find everything? Although the sample data makes this look OK, so needs clarification.

Comment: Looking to the data provide by OP seems the pattern of the reason_codes match .. is base on the first 3 char... so i suggested substr ..instead of like .. (like and between don't work togheter)

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to match the beginning of the `REASON_CODE` strings, you can do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table_1
WHERE REASON_CODE >= 'A10' AND REASON_CODE < 'A26'
```

This is equivalent to scaisEdge's answer, but it can take advantage of an index on the `REASON_CODE` column, which cannot be used if you first call `SUBSTR()`.

You have to use `>=` and `<` because `BETWEEN` includes both endpoints, and you want to match everything up to, but not including `A26`. You can't use `BETWEEN 'A10' AND 'A25'` because strings beginning with `A25` and having additional characters are higher than that.

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ( REASON_CODES ) AS
SELECT 'A00 VMC B10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A00 RTD B19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A09 RTD B19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ASD A10 B19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XYZ A20 RTD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC XYZ A25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A26 RTD B19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A99 RNT B40' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_NAME
WHERE  REGEXP_SUBSTR( REASON_CODES, 'A\d{2}' ) BETWEEN 'A10' AND 'A25';
```

**Output**:

```
REASON_CODES
------------
ASD A10 B19  
XYZ A20 RTD  
ABC XYZ A25
```